# My query gives me duplicated values (query of three tables)

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I extract the correct information?

I have the following tables:

```
FILE_INF
ORDER  STARTRUN         ENDRUN          NAME
11     20190729000100   20190729010100  APPLE
11     20190729020000   20190729030000  APPLE
.........

FILE_RUN
ORDER  GROUP
11     FRUITS
11     FRUITS
.....

FILE_LOG
ORDER  MESSAGE                     DATE
11     FILE ORDERED SUCCESFULLY    20190928
11     FILE ORDERED SUCCESFULLY    20190928
11     FILE_NOT_ORDERED            20190928
11     FILE_NOT_FOUND              20190928
```

My desired result should be:

```
ORDER  MESSAGE                     DATE        STARTRUN           ENDRUN           GROUP
11     FILE_ORDERED_SUCCESFULLY    20190928    20190729000100     20190729010100   FRUITS
11     FILE_ORDERED_SUCCESFULLY    21090928    20190729020000     20190729030000   FRUITS
```

My query gives me:

```
 11     FILE_ORDERED_SUCCESFULLY    20190928    20190729000100     20190729010100   FRUITS
 11     FILE_ORDERED_SUCCESFULLY    20190928    20190729000100     20190729010100   FRUITS
```

My code:

```
select A.NAME, C.MESSAGE, C.DATE, A.STARTRUN, A.ENDRUN, B.GROUP
     from 
         FILE_INF a
            inner join FILE_LOG c
            on a.ORDERNO = c.ORDERNO 
            inner join FILE_RUN b
            on A.ORDER = b.ORDER
            AND A.STARTRUN>='20190729000000' and A.ENDRUN<='20190729235959'
            AND C.MESSAGE like '%FILE_ORDERED%'
     order by A.STARTRUN, A.ENDRUN;
```

I don't understand why I get duplicated rows. I would like a row of every execution and not duplicate rows.

Comment: Your query seems ok and its also returning the result as per your desired output!!!

Comment: Your tables have multiple rows for the same "key" ORDERNO. So when you join on ORDERNO you get a product for all permutations of all the rows. This is a flaw in your data model. You need some additional column to qualify the ORDERNO so that you can tell with row in FILE_INF matches which row in FILE_RUN matches which rows in FILE_LOG.

Answer (score 0):

Just add distinct in your select before column names

```
    select distinct A.NAME, C.MESSAGE, 
    C.DATE, A.STARTRUN, A.ENDRUN, 
    B.GROUP
     from 
     FILE_INF a
        inner join FILE_LOG c
        on a.ORDERNO = c.ORDERNO 
        inner join FILE_RUN b
        on A.ORDER = b.ORDER
        AND A.STARTRUN>='20190729000000' and A.ENDRUN<='20190729235959'
        AND C.MESSAGE like '%FILE_ORDERED%'
 order by A.STARTRUN, A.ENDRUN;
```

Comment: Thanks, my question is... there is no option that I use the clause where in first join and then with that results execute the second join? Thanks

Comment: you can make it as a correlated subquery/simple subquery like `select * from (select cols from a,b) t , c where t.col=c.col...`